# What is the difference between neurotransmitters acting as neurotransmitters and hormones?

Tags: neuroscience, terminology, endocrinology, neurotransmitter

My main confusion is what differentiates the action of a transmitter substance as a neurotransmitter and as a hormone. For example, when norepinephrine is being talked about as transmitter substance that modulates brain responsiveness and information processing, it's a neurotransmitter. But when norepinephrine is involved in the functions of the autonomic nervous system (ANS), does it work as a hormone or a neurotransmitter?

Quoting from *Physiology of Behavior*, by N. Carlson, 2013 edition:

> "Neurons in the central nervous system contain a1- and a2-adrenergic
>   receptors and b1- and b2-adrenergic receptors. All four kinds of
>   receptors are also found in various organs of the body besides the
>   brain and are responsible for the effects of epinephrine and
>   norepinephrine **when they act as hormones outside the central nervous
>   system**."

So does that mean that whenever norepinephrine works outside the CNS, it works as a hormone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This figure from Campbell (2011), chapter 45, is very didactic and may clarify this nomenclature for you.

The processes of interest here are **a**, **d** and **e**:

[image]

The definition of hormone (in animals) is quite simple: a signaling molecule **released in the bloodstream**. That's the process **a** in the figure.

On the other hand, a neurotransmitter is released in the synapse, acting locally. That's the process **d** in the figure.

However, some nerve cells release their signaling molecule in the bloodstream (process **e** in the figure). Unlike the synaptic signaling, this molecule can act on a target cell at great distance.

So, despite the fact that we're talking about the very same molecule (norepinephrine in your example), in that last process this molecule is technically speaking a **hormone**, not a neurotransmitter anymore.

---

Source: Reece, J., Reece, J. and Campbell, N. (2011). Campbell biology. Boston: Pearson Learning Solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Right.  It's nomenclature to differentiate actions and release in the CNS (neuronal) versus outside (endocrine in this case). A neurotransmitter will act locally to it's release site typically from a neuronal synapse, while hormones tend to be released into the bloodstream and can act much further away as well as at a different time scale.

Source from textbook: Principles of Neural Science (Fourth Edition), Kandel et al. 2000, McGraw-Hill Medical ISBN 10: 0071120009